# Google maps loading before AJAX requests complete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, geolocation

I'm using **Google Maps API** with **rails 5.0.4**.

I'd like the map to center on the user location and fill the latitude, longitude fields with the coordinates. Currently, the *lat, lng* fields fill correctly, but the map loads before the async calls are completed, making the map position not match the coordinates. It does fix itself after a refresh, but on first load, the async is an issue. I tried to set this up with a promise but could not get it to work.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      function getUserCoordinates() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCoords);
        };
      };

      function setCoords(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
        updateUserLat(lat);
        updateUserLng(lng);
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat.toFixed(6);
        document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng.toFixed(6);
      };

      function updateUserLat(lat) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'PATCH',
          url: '/users/:id',
          data: {'user[latitude]': lat}
        });
      };
      function updateUserLng(lng) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'PATCH',
          url: '/users/:id',
          data: {'user[longitude]': lng}
        });
      };

      getUserCoordinates();

      function initMap(){
          initialize();
      };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move initMap() function from the document ready wrapper. Call initMap directly when you have your lat/long set.

Having it in the document ready wrapper will call to initialize the map when the page loads, which is what you don't want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I moved initMap outside of the wrapper and am now calling it directly. However, the way I've set up the map is to initialize with the center coordinates being read from the User model. So I'd like the AJAX requests to complete, ensuring the user model has been updated before the map loads.

So currently, the map still loads before model is updated.